# Selecting more after group-by while using join

Tags: sql, join, group-by

At the moment I am busy with two tables, *Students* and *Classes*. These two both contain a column *project_group*, a way to categorize multiple students from one class into smaller groups.

In the *Students* table there is a column *City* that states in which town/city students live, from the rows that have been filled there are already several cities occurring multiple times. The code I used to check how many times a city is being showed is this:

```
SELECT City, count(*)
FROM Students
GROUP BY City
```

Now the next thing I want to do is show per class in which cities the students live and how many live there, so for example a result like:

- A | - | 2
- A | New York | 3
- A | Los Angeles | 1
- B | - | 1
- B | Miami | 2
- B | Seattle | 1

*Students* and *Classes* can join each other on the column *project_group* but what I'm mostly interested in his using both the *GROUP BY* mentioned earlier, using the *JOIN* and also showing the results per class.

Thanks in advance,
KRAD

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Could you give an example of the columns contained in the two tables? Specifically what exactly are you looking to join the two tables with? This will help me write the query to give you an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: @HART CO I am using SQL Developer.

Comment: @Zi0n1 In the table **Classes** there are the columns **project_group** and **class_id**. **project_group** is what is used to join with the **Students** table.

Furthermore, in **Students** there are columns for; student id number, first name, last name, tussenvoegsels (It's Dutch, tussenvoegsels are what can be put between first and last names, for example 'van' in 'Vincent van Gogh'), e-mail, cell number, DOB, project group and city.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have already tried showing how many people live in one city, see the first code example in my question. Joining the tables also hasn't been an issue.
The issue is that I don't just want to show how many people live in a city, but also show this per class. The problem arises when in the SELECT more than just the 'City, count(*)' are used, the error that follows is: not a GROUP BY expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the column name is for A and B in your example.  I'm assuming Classes.Class in the following:

```
SELECT
  C.Class
  , S.City
  , COUNT(S.*) AS Count
FROM
  Classes AS C INNER JOIN 
  Students AS S ON C.Project_Group = S.Project_Group
GROUP BY
  C.Class
  , S.City
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work. I get a 'SQL command not properly ended'-error.

Could this perhaps have to do with the fact that **project_group** is spelled somewhat differently between the tables ? In **Students** it's **project_groep** whereas in **Classes** it's **project_group**.
I'm not certain why the names are not the same and using the same spelling is better for obvious reasons, but could this be the cause ?

Don't the names have to be the same for an inner join ?

Comment: No, the names don't need to be the same, but you need to indicate the names correctly in the "ON" portion of the join.  You'll notice that the "ON" uses the aliases assigned for each table (C or S) - so, you'll need to change S.Project_Group to S.Project_groep

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. While doing some tests to see which exact error message it was that I got, I used this and managed to get it working. I now get an overview per class that shows how many people live in which city. This is the code used.

```
SELECT class_id, city, count(*) AS amount
FROM students, classes
WHERE students.project_group = classes.project_group
GROUP BY class_id, city
ORDER BY class_id
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer provided by snow white yesterday, it's correct.  One thing to note is that you're using deprecated syntax, comma separated list of table names in `FROM` should be avoided, snow white's answer uses standards compliant join syntax, so I'd suggest accepting that answer.

Comment: @HartCO 
`SELECT class_id, city, count(*) AS amount
FROM students
JOIN classes ON (students.project_group = classes.project_group)
GROUP BY class_id, city
ORDER BY class_id`

Would be the better version then ?

Comment: Yep, don't need for the `()` around the join condition, but doesn't hurt at all, `JOIN...ON` is standard syntax now, it also helps avoid some ugly situations and muddled `WHERE` clauses when more tables are involved.